# Cannot use $http within angular factory (angular 1.x)

Tags: angularjs, http, angular-http

I have added $http at the start of the script but for some reason the $http isn't loaded - how do I log $http into the module rather than the controller

```
var abcdReportServices = angular.module('abcdReportServices', [ ]);

abcdReportServices.factory('uploadFileAjax', ['getPDFsImage', function(getPDFsImage) {
   return function(evt, $scope){
           $scope.http({
              method: "POST",
              url: 'someEndpoint/doSomething',
               data: $.param({
                 'name': 'name-of-rpt'
            }),
        headers: {
            "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        }
    }).success(
        function(data) {
            console.log("Saving success", data); 
        }
    );
   }

}
}]);
```

// error in console log

```
$http is not defined...
```

Comment: `$http` has to be injected, just like you are injecting `getPDFsImage`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to include `$http` in your factory's dependency injection and then switch your `$scope.http` to `$http`.

```
var abcdReportServices = angular.module('abcdReportServices', [ ]);

abcdReportServices.factory('uploadFileAjax', ['getPDFsImage', '$http', function(getPDFsImage, $http) {
   return function(evt){
           $http({
              method: "POST",
              url: 'someEndpoint/doSomething',
               data: $.param({
                 'name': 'name-of-rpt'
            }),
        headers: {
            "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        }
    }).success(
        function(data) {
            console.log("Saving success", data); 
        }
    );
   }

}
}]);
```